# Graylog geoip no showing all locations on the map

Tags: maxmind, graylog, ip-geolocation

I have a problem, that in the graylog Map view it doesn't show all the locations. Shows very few country codes, knowing that there exist a lot of countries, in the map view I can't get any of them. 
[Here you can find a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByCsX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Country code field is not enought to show point in map. You need coordinates field, with GPS coordinates (latitude,longitude format) to show point in map.

Check this articles:
https://www.graylog.org/post/how-to-set-up-graylog-geoip-configuration
https://www.graylog.org/post/implementing-geolocation-with-graylog-pipelines